# Can OnClick do 2 things?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This is the html code...

```
<div id="video-embeds">
<div id="Div1">
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="&#9658;" onclick="switchVisible();"  style="font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 2; background-color: #000; text-align: center; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 0px; z-index: 102; background: url('.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'fifu_image_url', TRUE).') no-repeat; background-size: cover; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; padding-top: 0px; height: 0; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 100%; font-size: 120px; line-height: 5;"/>

    </div>
    <div id="Div2" class="video-embed" style="font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 2; background-color: #000; text-align: center; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 0px; z-index: 102;display:none;">'.
    do_shortcode('[video_display]').'
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is the script...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function switchVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('Div1')) {

                if (document.getElementById('Div1').style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
}
</script>
```

I want to add url openning in new pop up window or new window also onclick input as

Something like...

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode( get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. You can do that in multiple different ways: 1. Just create a new function and do: `onclick="switchVisible();somethingElse();"`. 2. You can create one function that does all you want. 3. You can register the onclick event using JS (recommended) with [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). You can then add multiple eventListeners on the same element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use `addEventListener`, and just forget about the `onclick` attribute altogether. Remove the `onclick` in your `<button>` code and add this to the script:

```
document.getElementById("Button1").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   /* write code for stuff button is supposed to do when clicked */
});
```

This way, you are separating your JavaScript from your HTML, resulting in nicer code. Instead of calling an anonymous function `(e) => { ... }` or `function() { ... }`, you can call functions by name, and you can do this repeatedly, if you want multiple functions to run when the button is clicked:

```
document.getElementById("Button1").addEventListener("click", functionName1);
document.getElementById("Button1").addEventListener("click", functionName2);
/* etc... */
```

With that code, both `functionName1()` and `functionName2()` will run when the button is clicked.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

And make sure the `<script>` tag is the last element inside the `<body>` tag, so that the script does not interrupt the loading of the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can try bootstrap modal

[example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

OR

```
window.open('http://google.com');
```