# How to call two method in button click?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

How can I call two method in Button.click.I want that when I click button, one method runs in the code behind and another one in script tag.

Html:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnClick" />
```

Javascript:

```
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');
var btnUpdate = document.getElementById("btnUpdate")

btnUpdate.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal1.style.display = "none";
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtCode.Value = "Foo";
}
```

Now the method in the script tag works but another doesn't work.Please help me.
By the way I use Asp.Net.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can OnClick do 2 things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569445/can-onclick-do-2-things)

Comment: after loading browser only javascript will work. I hope you are using asp and its a server side language and it will not work after loading. If you want to call a server side script you need to call an api using ajax.

Comment: Can you give any example?

Answer (score -1):

The default behavior of a button is to submit the form to the server.

When using `e.preventDefault();` you prevent the form from being submitted to server, that's why the client code works and server doesn't.

Comment: I removed this string(`e.preventDefault();`). It works as I want.But the popup which is appeared by the method in the script immediately disappeared.What can I do?

Comment: do not remove it, leave it there and submit the form manually - with this approach the site does not get reloaded and the popup will stay as you expect. native: document.getElementById("myForm").submit();   jquery:  $( "form" ).submit();

Comment: I wrote your code string in scrip tag.But this time I don't see my popup.

Comment: The page is reloaded that's why your popup doesn't show up. I suggest you take a look at WebMethod, basically is a static method in your code behind that can receive Ajax calls.